# Telerik MVC Grid. How to bind to a nullable column

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, telerik, telerik-grid, telerik-mvc

I have a grid with a column which contains a nullable data

```
Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
   .Columns(columns =>
    {
       columns.Add(o => o.Foo);
    }
```

That works, but shows something like `[object Object]` on the client. Supposedly it should show Foo.Name, I tried to override Foo's ToString() - didn't work, I tried to change that into `columns.Add(o => o.Foo.Name);`, but then it doesn't want to render the entire grid. 
I tried to use `columns.Bound(o => o.Foo.Name);` - no results. BTW, what's the difference between `Add()` and `Bound()` ?

Comment: I guess the only solution is not to use null objects. o.Foo should contain at least a new empty instance of the Foo object, but never null

Comment: Normally, you'd use "columns.Bound(o => o.Foo.Name)" Can you better describe why it didn't work? Did it throw an error? Or what happened?

Comment: No errors... Just Doesn't render if there is a null. Busy indicator keeps rolling, That's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use the Template of the column to do this. Here is some code

```
Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
   .Columns(columns =>
    {
       columns.Add(o => o.Foo).Template(o =>
       {
          %>
             <%= o.Foo != null ? o.Foo.Name : "" %> 
          <%
       })
       .ClientTemplate("<#= Foo != null ? Foo.Name : '' #>");
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that `Model` is a collection of `RowData` instances, you could add a getter `FooName` to the `RowData` class:

```
public class RowData
{
    public string FooName
    {
        get { return Foo == null ? null :: Foo.Name; }
    }
}
```

Then you can bind to `FooName`:

```
Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(o => o.FooName);
    }
```

I can't test it at the moment. Possibly you need a setter as well. It doesn't need to do anything.

And I have no idea what `Add()` does. I've never used it.